# What does a string after pipe while defining an Apache beam pipeline signifies?

Tags: apache-beam

```
lines = pipeline | 'ReadFromText' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(
    'path/to/input-*.csv')
```

What is the significance of string 'ReadFromText' in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string after the pipe `|` is an optional way to name the step, and it can be named anything not necessarily matching the name of the `beam.io`.

The above code can also be written without naming the step like the following:

```
lines = pipeline | beam.io.ReadFromText(
    'path/to/input-*.csv')
```

The redirect key `>>` is only to be used when naming the step.

Comment: This could be useful if, say, one was reading two distinct (sets of) text files (e.g. with the intent of joining them). Explicitly naming the single `ReadFromText` as `"ReadFromText"` is just redundant.